# updateOne arguments for mongodb endpoint

Tags: mongodb-query, endpoint

I have the following endpoint for updateOne function as HTTPS Endpoint to MongoDB serveless instance.

My function is:

```
exports = function({ query, headers, body}, response) {
const result = context.services
.get('mongodb-atlas')
.db('gymlog')
.collection('exercises')
.updateOne({});


return  "Updated!";
};
```

via postman I've sent the body:

```
 { 
"query": {"id":"65a93d47a040369f2c8de4f5"},
 "update": {"exname": "Test update"}
 }
```

got the following error:
"error": "uncaught promise rejection: update: 2 args (query and update modifier) required",
"error_code": "UncaughtPromiseRejection"

I have other endpoint for Read, Write and Delete working but can't get this syntax correct.  Suggestions?

Comment: Your update statement does not look like a normal update operator to me. Have you checked out example in [this official documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/#std-label-update-operators)?